# IsolatedStorageFile usage throws AbandonedMutexException

Tags: silverlight, isolatedstorage

I am maintaining some code with a method in Silverlight 4.0, which threw

> IsolatedStorageException There is not enough free space to perform the operation.

, until I created the directory for it in my C:\Documents and Settings\(user)\Local Settings\Application Data directory. Now I get the slightly more annoying

> System.Exception occurred
>     Message=The wait completed due to an abandoned mutex.
>     StackTrace:
>          at System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, Int64 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
>     InnerException: null

The code below throws this exception on the call IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()

```
public object Getfromcache()
    {

        try
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFile file = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("AppCache/" + cachekey, FileMode.Open, file))

                if (stream.Length > 0)
                {
                    return serializer.ReadObject(stream);
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This code has not caused me any problems before. Does anyone see something horribly wrong with it?

Comment: Deleted my answer since clearly correcting a typo doesn't count.  To answer your question in the comment of the answer: braces are a device to hold up ones trousers, stereotypically worn by bankers in London.  Currently not all that popular right now for some reason .....  I'm refering to the braces not the bankers, of course.

Comment: It's embarrasing that a pun has to be explained to me :) Bankers aren't that popular around here these days.

Comment: It might be worth you correcting the typo in your code so that others don't provide the same answer I just deleted.

Comment: I get the same exception some times when I restart debugging a SL5 Sketchflow app with Visual Studio 2010. But my code doesn't do anything with the IsolatedStorage.

Comment: Does it happen on all machines, or just one?